# Problem accessing nested object in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem accessing an object within an object. I have a product with images. A product can have multiple images. I am able to query from the database and this is the result.

```
Bedsitter Price:7000
Loc: Opposite GG Apartment
image:{ "id": 16, "title": "26f16f925b189465.jpg", "filename": "26f16f925b189465.jpg", "created_at": "2021-01-24T16:12:35.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-01-24T16:12:35.000000Z", "pivot": { "products_id": 10, "images_id": 16 } }
```

My problem is getting filename from the image object.
here is my Vue script

```
     <div v-for="product in Products.data" :key="product.id" class="p-2">
         <div class="item p-2">{{product.id}}</div>
          <div class="item p-2">{{product.title}} Price:{{product.price}} </div>
          <div class="item p-2"><p>Loc:{{product.location}}</p></div>
             <div class="item p-2"><p>fff:{{product.images[0]}}</p></div>
         <div class="item p-2"> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
   :href="'/products/'+product.id">View</a>
         </div>
```

defination

```
export default {
        data(){
         return{
         Products:{},
         images:{},
         
           id:'',
           name:'',
           filename:''

         }
    },
```

I have tried using product.images[0].id and product.images[0]['id'] but no success. am not sure what am missing kindly help.

Comment: Details are bit confusing , you have images as object. & you are trying to treat as array. Also you have mentioned one statement as image object.  There are images ,image  two diff thing mentioned on description

Comment: @KaushikThanki What am trying to achieve is to display a single image for each product. A product can have multiple images.ie there is a relationship. For now am able to query from the database and list in view. For product id and price there is no problem but when I add product.images[0] i get the whole object. So I want to extract the data from the object.

Comment: Could you please share your json list of Products.data ?

Comment: The json format 
{
  "id": 11,
  "title": "Single",
  "description": "Spacious",
  "price": 3000,
  "location": "Egp near Plx",
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 18,
      "title": "fine.jpg",
      "filename": "fine.jpg",
      "pivot": {
        "products_id": 11,
        "images_id": 18
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "title": "Koala.jpg",
      "filename": "Koala.jpg",
          "pivot": {
        "products_id": 11,
        "images_id": 19
      }
    },
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-shr7in?file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue

App URL : https://vue-shr7in.stackblitz.io

```
<div v-for="product in Products" :key="product.id" class="p-2">
        <div class="item p-2">{{product.id}}</div>
        <div class="item p-2">{{product.title}} Price:{{product.price}} </div>
        <div class="item p-2">
            <p>Loc:{{product.location}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item p-2">
            <p>fff:{{product.images[0].filename}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item p-2"> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" :href="'/products/'+product.id">View</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

data:

```
data(){
    return {
      Products: [  {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "Single",
    "description": "Spacious",
    "price": 3000,
    "location": "Egp near Plx",
    "images": 
    [
      {
        "id": 18,
        "title": "fine.jpg",
        "filename": "fine.jpg",
        "pivot": {
          "products_id": 11,
          "images_id": 18
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "title": "Koala.jpg",
        "filename": "Koala.jpg",
        "pivot": {
          "products_id": 11,
          "images_id": 19
        }
      },
    ]
  }  ]
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you template is working with that data but still having a problem now accessing from the actual data. How should it appear in return type but this gives an error  Products:{images:{filename:''}} undefined. If you don't mind help me in this part. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3736334 i guess you are not getting difference between array & object.  in your case images is array not object & you are treating it as object.

Comment: True I think that may true and I dont know why am taking much time to get it. I have changed to this      Products:{ images:[]},filename:''  and has also tried  Products:{ images:[filename]}''   but how to define the  filename coz i get undefined.

Comment: please create a stackblitz project which shows issue.

Comment: @KauShil Check the code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-e3gpen?file=src/components/Record.vue